# EWS Managed API SyncFolderItems How to Update and Delete/Keeping track of items

Tags: c#, exchange-server, ews-managed-api

I am building an app that is required to live in a trusted domain, monitor a collection of mailbox-calendars on an exchange server in that domain, and sync appointments to different mailboxes on one or many other servers.  The mailbox it is synced with is defined in an internal mapping table (sqlce) that is maintained by the user of this application.

The problem I have is I can not work out a way to keep track of the remote appointment so that I can update or delete it if necessary.  After I create the appointments on the remote server they have a new itemid which does not correspond to the one returned by the sync folder items call on the local exchange server.  I can't find the item by start time/subject as these may have been changed or deleted.

My sync method is below - am I going about this entirely the wrong way or is there a better way to use the SyncFolderItems method?

The best approach I have come up with so far to get around my problem is to save ItemID of the remote appointment into a property of the local appointment but even this I am not sure will work because I don't know what properties are maintained after a delete? Please Help!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;
using System.Net;

namespace ProExchangeSync2012
{
    class ExchangeWebServiceMethods
    {

    public string ProExchangeSyncCalendars(string LocalMailbox
                                                ,string RemoteMailbox
                                                ,string SyncState    
                                                ,ExchangeService RemoteService
                                                ,ExchangeService LocalService
                                                )
    {
        //if SyncState is empty string set to null
        if (SyncState.ToString().Length == 0)
        { SyncState = null; }

        ExchangeService LocalExchangeService = LocalService;
        ExchangeService RemoteExchangeService = RemoteService;
        RemoteExchangeService.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress,RemoteMailbox);


        //Folders and mailboxes to pass to the webservice in SyncItems call.
        Mailbox DonorMailBox = new Mailbox(LocalMailbox);
        Mailbox DestinationMailBox = new Mailbox(RemoteMailbox);
        FolderId DonorFolder = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, DonorMailBox);
        FolderId DestinationFolder = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, DestinationMailBox);

        //Create a ChangeCollection object and call syncfolderitems on local exchange service.
        ChangeCollection<ItemChange> ItemChanges
        = LocalExchangeService.SyncFolderItems(new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, DonorMailBox) //PASS IN THE MAILBOX HERE>
                                        , PropertySet.FirstClassProperties
                                        , null
                                        , 512
                                        , SyncFolderItemsScope.NormalItems
                                        , SyncState
                                        );


        //Store the SyncState
        SyncState = ItemChanges.SyncState;

        //Fetch all the required properties of the items
        //LocalService.LoadPropertiesForItems(ItemChanges, PropertySet.FirstClassProperties);

        if (ItemChanges.Count == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There are no items to synchronize.");
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (ItemChange ic in ItemChanges)
            {
                if (ic.ChangeType == ChangeType.Create)
                {
                    Appointment lappointment = Appointment.Bind(LocalExchangeService, ic.ItemId);
                    Appointment rappointment = new Appointment(RemoteExchangeService);
                    rappointment.Subject = lappointment.Subject;
                    rappointment.Start = lappointment.Start;
                    rappointment.Body = lappointment.Body;
                    rappointment.End = lappointment.End;
                    rappointment.Location = lappointment.Location;
                    rappointment.Save();

                }

                else if (ic.ChangeType == ChangeType.Update)
                {
                    //Bind to the local appointment and get the start date
                    Appointment lappointment = Appointment.Bind(LocalExchangeService, ic.ItemId);
                    DateTime StartDate = lappointment.Start;
                    ItemId ItemToUpdate = ItemIDSearch(RemoteExchangeService,StartDate,lappointment.Subject);
                    //Bind to the remote appointment using ItemToUpdate & update all the details 
                    //this is is less intensive than comparing the appointments for changes.
                    Appointment rappointment = Appointment.Bind(RemoteExchangeService, ItemToUpdate);
                    rappointment.Subject = lappointment.Subject;
                    rappointment.Start = lappointment.Start;
                    rappointment.Body = lappointment.Body;
                    rappointment.End = lappointment.End;
                    rappointment.Location = lappointment.Location;
                    rappointment.Save();

                }
                else if (ic.ChangeType == ChangeType.Delete)
                {
                    Appointment lappointment = Appointment.Bind(LocalExchangeService, ic.ItemId.UniqueId);
                    DateTime StartDate = lappointment.Start;
                    ItemId ItemToUpdate = ItemIDSearch(RemoteExchangeService, StartDate, lappointment.Subject);
                    Appointment rappointment = Appointment.Bind(RemoteExchangeService, ic.ItemId.UniqueId);
                    rappointment.Delete(DeleteMode.MoveToDeletedItems);
                }

            }
        }


        return SyncState;
    }
    //End of Sync Method

    //Below method returns a single itemid from exchange service based on start datetime of an appointment in a mailbox.
    public ItemId ItemIDSearch(ExchangeService ExchangeService, DateTime AppointmentStart, string subject)
    {
        ItemId FoundItem;
        ItemView iv = new ItemView(1000);
        iv.Traversal = ItemTraversal.Associated;

        SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection searchFilterCollection =  new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And);
        searchFilterCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(AppointmentSchema.Subject,subject));
        searchFilterCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(AppointmentSchema.Start, AppointmentStart));

        FindItemsResults<Item> fiitems = ExchangeService.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, searchFilterCollection, iv);

        if (fiitems.Items.Count == 1)//if we only get one result do the work else return null
        {
            FoundItem = fiitems.Items[0].Id;
        }

        FoundItem = null;

        return FoundItem;          
    }


}
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

So the final solution to all this, which came from the messiah of Exchange Web Services, Glen Scales, was that I stored the "CleanGlobalObjectId" of the appointments I was synching with in my internal database along with the EWS UniqueId that is returned when calling the EWS SyncFolderItems method.

Using the CleanGlobalObjectId which is an extended property of the appointment, I was always able to find a specific appointment on the server even if it had been hard deleted, because the value of this property never changes.